AI service to extract text and train model based on user input if extracted text is incorrect
I am working with highly unstructured legal documents like contracts,lease or rental documents and trying to extract data and incorporate feedback loop so that the human corrections can be fed in and train the model. Wondering which is the right AI service to do this.

you can't do much with feedbacks apart from RL/evolutionary strategies
